# use allowedFilter() for relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

hello i am trying to filter data from relation table.
like table is

```
TrainingVideo(table)
   -> Media(table)
```

code like

---

```
$a = QueryBuilder::for(TrainingVideo::class)
            ->with('grade','media')
            ->allowedFilters(['name', 'grade_id'], allowedFilters(AllowedFilter::exact('media.is_help_center', null, false))
            ->get();
```

---

TrainingVideo field is name and grade_id and media field is is_help_center.

trying to filter data and got error like

> "Requested filter(s) `name, grade_id` are not allowed. Allowed filter(s) are `is_help_center`."
> refer allowedfilter from this link  [https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v3/features/filtering#:~:text=An%20allowed%20filter%20can%20be,AllowedFilter%3A%3Apartial()%20filters.](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v3/features/filtering#:%7E:text=An%20allowed%20filter%20can%20be,AllowedFilter%3A%3Apartial()%20filters.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get where you saw you can this ?

`allowedFilters(AllowedFilter::exact('media.is_help_center', null, false)`

Maybe I missed something but as far as I know, there is no `allowedFilters` helper function.

Anyway, you can probably do

```php
$a = QueryBuilder::for(TrainingVideo::class)
            ->with('grade','media')
            ->allowedFilters(
                array_merge(
                    ['name', 'grade_id'],
                    AllowedFilter::exact('media.is_help_center', null, false)
                )
            )
            ->get();
```

Don't forget to import `AllowedFilter` at the top of your file with

`use Spatie\QueryBuilder\AllowedFilter;`

Once this is setup, is should work.